# what is the meaning of command "@:" inside the linux kernel 4.4 Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

### I am trying to understand the linux kernel 4.4.37 makefile, and there is one line (line 147) that confuse me:

```
$(filter-out _all sub-make $(CURDIR)/Makefile, $(MAKECMDGOALS)) _all: sub-make
    @:
```

---

because there is a "tab" before "@:", so I think it is a command for the rule above, but I do not know what "@:" means

could any one help me? thank you

Comment: The `@` prefix of course tells _make_ not to echo the command on stdout before it gets executed. What command? The `:` command of course. This is a useful `sh` built-in that merely returns 0 (success).